# how can I convert a big pandas dataframe to a streaming data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stream

[image]I have a pandas dataframe that includes timestamps, id, products, price and with more than 50+ columns.

I'd like to convert this data frame to a streaming data frame. For example, every 10 seconds, I'd like to receive 10 raws or 1 raw then after next 10 raws or 1 raw until the data frame ends.

I had a look to streamz library but couldn't find a proper function for this.

In this way, I am planning to apply some visualisation, and do some functional aggregations or further analysis.

```
>>>df.head()
```

Comment: if you try this "df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=2)" this will return iterator and you can loop over df to perform some actions. The above statement will return 2 rows on each iteration

Comment: how can I add period to this like 10 seconds? looking for more a library solution for this instead of creating all libraries from scratch

Comment: you won't get any ready solutions. If you wish to add time then either you can use schedule library(https://github.com/dbader/schedule) to schedule such job or time.sleep will also work, this will entirely depend on your end to end workflow.

Comment: The only thing I try to solve is enabling dataframe to act like streaming. If nones did this before, I will create an open-source library for that for sure. But have seen good examples in streamz library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this small solution to your question.

```
import pandas as pd
import schedule

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=2)

def get_next_row():
    row = next(df)
    print(row)
    # do_some_thing_with_row(row)

schedule.every(5).seconds.do(get_next_row)

while True:
    try:
        schedule.run_pending()
    except StopIteration as e:
        print("EOF")
        break
```

The above code basically calls ***get_next_row*** function and read every 2 rows in 5 seconds of interval and prints the rows. Instead of printing you can add your functionality. Once it reach EOF, it will throw ***StopIteraton*** exception.

Now you can play around interval and chunk size to suit your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Previously I have gotten around a similar problem by using `pd.date_range()` to create times with the desired interval, then slicing the original dataframe by the times in the range.

For example.

```
times = pd.date_range(start=13:00, end=15:00, freq=T)
for t in times:
    df_instance = df[df["Time"]<t]
    Do something
```